# Azure Backup - Is last backup copy retained indefinitely?

Tags: backup, azure, virtual-machines, cloud

If I enable Azure Backup on a VM and, after a few recovery points are saved, I disable Azure Backup, is the newest recovery point kept indefinitely, regardless of the retention policy?

I saw the following text in [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/migration-classic-resource-manager-faq#vault) and need to confirm if that is true:

> Backup copies will be pruned as per retention range. However, last
>   backup copy is always kept until you explicitly delete backup data.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Backup gives two options while stopping the backup schedule - you can retain the data or delete the data.

If you selected delete data option, it will delete backup data.

Once you stopped protection but selected to retain data, it will go to Backup Stopped State. You can go to VM at any point time, and select to Delete backup data. This will immediately delete backup data.

If you don't do any action, backups will be pruned as per retention but one copy of data is always maintained to give recoverability for the VM.